# Extend wireless network from DSL router with Airport Express

Tags: network, wifi, airport

This is what I want to do:

> ISP's DSL router (LAN port) <-- ethernet cable --> (WAN port) Airport Express

*(I know it's not possible to extend non Apple WiFi points wirelessly, so I need the ethernet cable).*

Then I'd like the Express to extend the existing DSL network, using the same SSID, password and security type.

It sounds simple but I've burned most of a day trying every combination I can think of and I cannot get this working!

Can anyone offer step by step instructions on the setup required via the Airport Utility app please? :)

*Note that each time I've tried a new combination I've factory reset the router (hold the reset for +5 seconds whilst powering it on) and have done multiple reboots of the DSL router.*

Comment: Where is it failing?

Comment: 1. Connect your express (LAN port) directly to your mac ethernet and fire up airport utility.
2. Discover it (you may have to click on "Other Base stations" and pick LAN)
3. Select Create New Network rather than extend when configuring.
4. Under Wireless, enter the identical NAME, Security Type, and Password as your DSL.
5 Under Network, select Bridged.
6. Let Airport setup finish, then unplug your express from the mac.

Comment: What is confusing me is your word "Extending" you are not extending unless you have a WiFi already (provided by the ISP-DSL). So to clarify, are you extending the existing WiFi or setting up a new one.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks for this.
I'm extending an existing Wifi network provided by the DSL. Setting up a new one is easy - it works fine - but I don't want two networks, I want one which I have extended to cover more of the house.
And... despite the fact that I'd swear I'd already done exactly this, albeit over wifi rather than plugged direcly in to the Airport, that seems to have done the trick! At least the router is happy (rare today) and the network is still fast (never happened before when I'd managed to get the router happy!). Thanks! Make it an answer! :)

Comment: (I know it's not possible to extend non Apple WiFi points wirelessly, so I need the ethernet cable).

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are set up instructions that should work for you:

1. Connect your express (LAN port) directly to your Mac ethernet and fire up Airport  Utility (you may want to do a factory reset first).
2. Discover it (you may have to click on "Other Base stations" and pick LAN).
3. Select Create New Network, rather than Extend, when configuring.
4. Select a separate password and enter the same password as the DSL router for the Wireless Password (and something you'll remember for the Base Station password).
5. Let Airport setup finish.
6. Edit the settings and under Wireless, enter the *identical* NAME, Security Type (for example; WPA2-Personal), and Password as your DSL router (the password will already be filled in from above of course).
7. Under Network, select; Off (Bridge Mode).
8. Unplug your Airport from the Mac and plug it in to the ethernet
   connection to the DSL router and the WAN connection on the Airport.

Comment: For anyone else doing this, consider using an ethernet running over the powerlines to avoid having to use ethernet cables ("HomePlug" is a defacto standard).